# how to get back to application from browser

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone, what i done is place a button and in button click event i call a web browser it works fine. but i cant able to get back to my application screen.By pressing the menu button of iphone ie will quit directly how can i get back to my application. pls help me thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your app register a custom URL scheme yourapp:// which you can then embed as a link in your web page - clicking on it in MobileSafari would launch your app. based on the scheme URL construct you can send data back to your app via this URL scheme:

yourapp://sometokenorvaluetopassback

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW27

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleOpenURL:

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, iphone OS is a single thread OS. once you are in a browser, you could not go back to your application.

Comment: It's not a single threaded OS, but it's true that you can only be running one application at once, except for a few built in exceptions (music can play in the background, Safari will stay running, etc). iPhone OS 4.0 allows multitasking, but only on some hardware.

Comment: how can i come back to my application after completion of web browser

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want this sort of functionality, you'll need to open the URL in a web view inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

I am impressed that Apple did not provide a gesture for go-back-to-previous app on iOS, probably they will add one in a future version after they file a patent on it ;)

Currently the only workaround is to register your own aplication URI (URL). As you can imagine this will work only for your app.